# код с использованием pyqiwip2p выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, p2p, pyqiwi

написал программу с использованием библиотеки pyqiwip2p но одна часть кода:

`bill = p2p.bill(amount = 1, lifetime=20, comment=str(call.message.chat.id) + f"{config.items[SelectedCardId][2]}")`

выдает ошибку:

`ValueError: Qiwi response is not JSON. This is Qiwi-side bug. Please try again later.`

Comment: `Qiwi response is not JSON. This is Qiwi-side bug`, скорее всего, у сервера киви какая-то ошибка произошла и тот в ответе вернул html страницу. Вы можете сами это проверить, добавив отладочные сообщения в код библиотеки киви, и если я прав, то ничего с этим не поделать - с вашей стороны нужно обработать ошибку, хотя бы показать ее пользователю, при большем желании можно сохранить в какую-нибудь очередь детали запроса и повторить его позже. Еще вы можете попробовать узнать о проблеме у автора библиотеки, например через issues / bug tracker, но я бы лучше сначала попробовал самим разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что я вводил не правильный секретный ключ киви, его надо было брать с сайта https://p2p.qiwi.com/ , а я брал с этого: https://qiwi.com/api